# How to render an html file in a Spring Controller route?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, flask

I'm building a local web server using IntelliJ, Maven & Spring. When I return Spring's @Controller the location of the /resources/static/jimi.html , the Java server just prints the String to the screen as opposed to rendering the html file.

I am new to the spring framework. I followed the start.spring.io tutorial to setup a java web app. I currently have the base set up and running using IntelliJ (default). My issue is the following: I can only figure out how to successfully return type String to localhost:8080/jimi.

I usually code in Python, and I understand that the Spring framework has the @Controller wrapper similar to the Flask @app.route wrapper in Python. I want to return an html file instead of a String, but can't figure out how. I have written the following which successfully serves String content on my local maven server:

```
@Controller
public class ShelfController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(){
        return "You are here";
    }

    @GetMapping("/jimi")
    @ResponseBody
    public String jimi(){
        //STUCK HERE
    }
}
```

The first route "localhost:8080/" works fine and prints the "Your are here" String to the screen. When I open the inspector, I see that it is returning the String to the body of this auto-generated html file.

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body>
    "You are here"
</body>
</html>
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
src ____ main ____ java ____ com.book.shelf ____ ShelfController.java
    \         \
     \         \__ resources ____ templates ...
      \                      \ 
       \__test ...            \__ static ____ jimi.html
```

I am looking for some line of (Java-Spring) code similar to Python-Flask's

```
@app.route("/jimi")
def jimi():
    return render_template("jimi.html")
```

which would return the jimi.html template at a given route 127.0.0.1:8080/jimi

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: By implementing thymeleaf.

1) move jimi.html to src/main/resources/templates repository

2) function should return the String "jimi" (without ".html")

3) remove @ResponseBody annotation from "/jimi" route

4) jimi.html needs < html xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org" >

5) add the thymeleaf spring dependency to pom.xml

```
//SHELFCONTROLLER.JAVA CODE
@Controller
public class ShelfController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(){
        return "You are here";
    }


    @GetMapping("/jimi")
    public String jimi(){
        return "jimi";
    }
}

//JIMI.HTML CODE
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<html xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>Hendirx is a Voodoo Chile</body>
</html>

//ADD TO POM.XML
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```